# Show Response of Ajax request

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, mongodb

```js
public ArrayList getConsignmentsID(final DB database, String searchValue) {
    System.out.println("inside getConsignmentsID function");
    Consignment consignment = new Consignment();
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection("mongodb://localhost", "transport");
    dbConnection.open();
    DBCollection conCollection = dbConnection.getDatabase().getCollection("consignment");
    List dbCursor = null;
    if (searchValue != null) {
      BasicDBObject searchObj = new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^" + searchValue));
      dbCursor = conCollection.find(searchObj, new BasicDBObject("_id", "true")).toArray();
      dbConnection.close();
      ArrayList consignmentList = new ArrayList();
      for (DBObject x: dbCursor) {
        System.out.println(x);
        consignmentList.add(x.get("_id"));
      }
      return consignmentList;
    } else {
      return null;
    } //System.out.println(new > BasicDBObject("consignmentList",consignmentList)); }
```

By Ajax Call i am getting this response from the json string in javascript

> { "consignmentList" : [ "" , "AAA" , "ABC" , "BHU" , "MAN" , "WER" , "ZXC"]}

and i want to parse this array string in javascript and display its values in the unodered list. and the backend response from the database is.

> { "_id" : ""}
>   { "_id" : "AAA"}
>   { "_id" : "ABC"}
>   { "_id" : "BHU"}
>   { "_id" : "MAN"}
>   { "_id" : "WER"}
>   { "_id" : "ZXC"}

```js
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var consignmentID = $('#consignmentID').val();
    var consignmentList = $('#consignmentList');
    if (consignmentID.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/jqueryreturn',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: JSON,
            data: {
                consignmentID: consignmentID
            },
            success: function(data) {


                consignmentList.show();
                consignmentList.html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#consignmentList').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#consignmentID').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#consignmentList').hide();
}
```

```html
<div  ><label style="margin:15px 0 0 0;" >Consignment:</label><input onkeyup="autocomplet()" id="consignmentID" type="text" class="inputlt"     name="consignmentId" value="${(consign._id)!""}" id="c" style="font-size: 16px "  onclick="clearInput(this)">
        <ul id="consignmentList"></ul>
```

```js
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var consignmentID = $('#consignmentID').val();
    var consignmentList = $('#consignmentList');
    if (consignmentID.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/jqueryreturn',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: JSON,
            data: {
                consignmentID: consignmentID
            },
            success: function(data) {


                consignmentList.show();
                consignmentList.html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#consignmentList').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(data) {
    // change input value
    $('#consignmentID').val(data);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#consignmentList').hide();
}
```

```html
<div  ><label style="margin:15px 0 0 0;" >Consignment:</label><input onkeyup="autocomplet()" id="consignmentID" type="text" class="inputlt"     name="consignmentId" value="${(consign._id)!""}" id="c" style="font-size: 16px "  onclick="clearInput(this)">
        <ul id="consignmentList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way...

```
success: function(data) {
   var res = "";
   for(var i=0; i<data.consignmentList.length; i++)
    {
       res +="<li>"+data.consignmentList[i]+"</li>";
    }
    consignmentList.html(res).show();

            }
```

Comment: Database Connection Closed
{ "_id" : ""}
{ "_id" : "AAA"}
{ "_id" : "ABC"}
{ "_id" : "BHU"}
{ "_id" : "MAN"}
{ "_id" : "WER"}
{ "_id" : "ZXC"}
Database Connection Closed
inside postConsignmentList function
Database Connection opened for URL=localhost/127.0.0.1:27017  Database=transport
inside getConsignmentsID function
Database Connection opened for URL=localhost/127.0.0.1:27017  Database=transport
Database Connection Closed
{ "_id" : "WER"}
Database Connection Closed
inside postConsignmentList function
Database Connection opened for URL=localhost/127.0.0.1:27017  Database=transport

Comment: Response is coming but not showing in the ul of html as list

Comment: Yes because response is not just the JSON it is having many other things. First try to resolve the error in PHP. then my code will work fine.